# What reference do I need to add to use OpenGL in vs2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl

What assembly do I need to add to my project to use OpenGL in VS2010 in C#?

would like to type

```
using OpenGL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Tao: http://www.mono-project.com/Tao

Answer (score 2):

Check out the OpenTK library.  That should provide you with the OpenGL functionality you're looking for.  The [documentation on the OpenGL implementation](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics) gives some code examples you can use to get started.